# Acquiring clear population density map

Tags: export, mapping

[image]

[image]

These images show the population density in every square unit. What I want is a map with the values of population density paired to a colour, like these.

However, these maps are not pixel-perfect: They are interpolated/hazy.

I have searched throughout the internet, and found this image (a peculiar TIFF file, [link](https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v4-population-density-rev11/data-download#)):

[image]

However, if one looks closely, the average population density of, say India, is the same as that of Norway. The map is not accurate. Some areas have 0 population, while some have a maximum number of people.

I want to have a map that can be read by a program easily, and display each coordinate's population density.

How do I do this with the TIFF file, or is there a better map than this?

I do not want to find the exact magnitudes of pop. density value of each pixel. As long as I can compare the values of one area to another reasonably, I am fine.

---

[image]

This image actually helps me. It only has 9 levels of density though.

Comment: @MrXsquared Basically, I want to acquire population density data per square unit (km or anything) from anywhere, whether it be these maps, other maps, or creating one myself. As long as I have numbers, I am good.

Comment: What you are asking (in your comment) is very broad and not really within the guidelines of GIS SE. Your question title also does not reflect what you actually want. I recommend having a read of [How to ask a good question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is "a program" for you?

Comment: @bugmenot123 A program is anything that can process the map to find the numbers. To be precise, I am trying to make a scenario where the world goes to total war. That means populations adjacent to each other from different countries must fight. That is what I am calculating - which of any two pixels must conquer the other. That is based on population density for now.

Comment: The map is not showing the same population in India as Norway. Population *density* is very non-uniform in most developed/developing countries where the vast majority of the population live in tiny urban areas. That's only a few pixels on this map. The rest looks close to zero by comparison. Did you add up all the India pixels and compare with the sum of Norway pixels? Did you also multiply by the pixel *area* because the is a *density* map and not a population *count* map? (GPW4 does have count maps but you linked to density) The GPW4 maps are correct.

Comment: @Spacedman I meant to ask for a map which shows the number of people in each pixels (I have one now). I wanted to know how the rural pixels of Norway have the same number of people as the urban areas of India.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that you are looking for can be accessed here: https://www.worldpop.org/project/categories?id=3

Some details about this:

> WorldPop produces different types of gridded population count
> datasets, depending on the methods used and end application.  .....
>
> Bespoke methods used to produce datasets for specific individual countries are available through the WorldPop Open Population
> Repository (WOPR) link below. These are 100m resolution gridded
> population estimates using customized methods ("bottom-up" and/or
> "top-down") developed for the latest data available from each country.
> They can also be visualised and explored through the woprVision App.
> The remaining datasets in the links below are produced using the
> "top-down" method, with either the unconstrained or constrained
> top-down disaggregation method used. Please make sure you read the
> Top-down estimation modelling overview page to decide on which
> datasets best meet your needs. Datasets are available to download in
> Geotiff and ASCII XYZ format at a resolution of 3 and 30 arc-seconds
> (approximately 100m and 1km at the equator, respectively)

Comment: The TIFF file does not help me, but the yellow-green map does (See above). Thanks a lot!